# VLC find out when movie stops from cmd

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

I am working with VLC from C# by creating a process that opens the command line.

Is there any way of knowing when a movie ended in from the command line or something ?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `vlc://quit` to the playlist after the intended file you want to play, VLC will quit after playback has finished. This is surely possible to catch from the command-line.

(Perhaps this is also what you *really* are trying to do: quit VLC after playback has finished and let the script continue.)

Answer (score 1):

```
vlc.exe file.xxx vlc:quit
```

Then, wait for your process to terminate:

```
var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(); 
info.FileName = @"c:\path\to\vlc.exe file.xxx vlc:quit"; 
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
process.StartInfo = info; 
process.Start(); 

//Wait for the process to be completed 
process.WaitForExit(); 

//It's finished. Enter your code here.
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that VLC has a command-line varient (CVLC/CVLC.exe) which is functionally the same, however it simply launches a video window that has no controls or menus unless you explicity enable them. Which depending on your usage may be a slightly improved situation.